# Renormalization in one-dimensional Ising model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, renormalization, ising-model

This is a question about the renormalization group (RG) in the one-dimensional Ising model. See for example exercise 5.13 In Chandler, Introduction to Modern Statistical Mechanics.

Suppose one uses the RG from small K = J/T to large K, in other words from large temperature T to small temperature. Suppose one approximates the free energy for large temperature, and then applies the RG many times. Why does the free energy for smaller and smaller temperature so obtained become more and more accurate?

Here is more information (from page 141 in Chandler). If $g(K)$ is the free energy per spin up to a factor of the temperature, then the RG flow  is

$K = 1/2 \cosh^{-1} ( e^{2 K'} )$

and

$g(K) = 1/2\ g(K') + 1/2\ \log 2 + K'/2$

For small K, interactions between spins are nearly negligible, thus $g(0.01) \approx \log 2$.
This is close to the exact value $g(0.01) = 0.693 197$. The difference is 0.0000499992

Applying the RG gives $K'=0.100334$, and $g(K') \approx 0.698147$. The difference with the exact value is 0.0000249996. This is twice as accurate as before. This can be continued: each RG steps gives results that are more accurate.

Comment: This question is a bit underspecified.  Perhaps you could state precisely what approximation you have in mind?

Comment: I have added more information in the question.